# What's the target in my data for training a stock price predictor?

Tags: csv, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, data-cleaning, data-processing

I want to build a stock price predictor for an economical indicator in Venezuela, I've cleaned and structured the historical data that I want to use (from the last 10 years), but I have doubts because it's my first machine learning project, my CSV data with 3000+ entries looks like this:

```
2553
11-28-2017;0.8823561
2554
11-29-2017;0.9679446
2555
11-30-2017;0.9719271
2556
12-1-2017;1.0302427
```

As you can see column 0 have the date and column 1 have the price for that particular date, in this case the training data (X) should be the price, however the methods that I want to use expect both X and Y (supervised learning), since it's my first time obtaining my own data I feel a bit lost, there you have my code so far: https://github.com/marcelodiaz558/Venezuela-dollar-price-predictor/blob/development/model.ipynb I would like to train my model in the future with a LSTM or maybe I'll start with a simple Artificial Neural Network for testing, when I solve my doubts about the data, I don't know who Y should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Y` / your target is what you want to predict. `X` / your training data is some vector representation of your prior knowledge that can be used to better your predictions of the unknown quantity. In a simple time-series prediction with a simple regressor, your training data could be the prices from the past N days.

So using your example data where you want to be able to predict the price one day in the future based on the prices from the last two days (`N=2`), your `X` and `Y` would be

```
X = [[0.8823561, 0.9679446], [0.9679446, 0.9719271]]
Y = [0.9719271, 1.0302427]
```

So to do machine learning on your data you would need to pre-process your data depending on exactly what you want. Some algorithms are specifically designed for this task, so will either not need pre-processing or it is done automatically in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you picked a difficult problem to start with ML: [Time Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series)

The issue here is that you has to respect the order of your values.

So a timeseries has:

```
Timestamp t-3: 0.8823561
Timestamp t-2: 0.9679446
Timestamp t-1: 0.9719271
Timestamp t(prediction/ y): 1.0302427
```

A really nice package comes with R which is called: [ARIMA](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/arima.html).
A problem is that you have to check if you have seasonal data (some patterns which regular occur in your data), stationary data (if the data trends to be stationary).

My recommendation, if you only want to start machine learning go for a classification problem with the iris dataset.